# CSS3 transition leaves a trail

Tags: google-chrome, css-transitions, jquery-transit

It happens sometimes with particular text, transitioning with CSS3. I do not know the reason why it happens and thus I cannot recreate the same in jsfiddle.

But you can look at 4th slide (the one with 5 rings) here,

http://jashwant.github.io/kickass-slider/

*Cool* text leaves a trail while animating and trail gets removed after sometime. But other text works okay without leaving any trail. I am not able to find out the problem.

How can I avoid this trail ?

(I am using latest linux chrome 26.0.1410.63)

*p.s. I am using jquery-transit to animate.*

See the `Cool` in picture.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

[Here's more detailed answer](http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d)

Comment: This is probably a bug in Chrome.  I see similar behavior in 27.0.1453.65 beta-m.  You should probably create a reduced test case and file a bug.

Comment: but I am unable to reproduce the same in a test case.

Comment: On Linux with Chrome Version 26.0.1410.63, I see no trail

Comment: @NikMartin, I am using the same and I see the trail. May be you didnt notice. I am attaching a picture of same.

Comment: @Jashwant, I'm pretty sure: http://i.imgur.com/0005J2k.jpg

Comment: Hmm. May be a hardware issue ?  Intel i3 , 3G RAM :P

Comment: This is a known Chrome bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142341

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can make the moving objects hardware-accelerated in Chrome, until the bug is fixed. Simply add the line

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to the definition of your slider objects (In my test, I added it to:

```
.slider > li > .object {
```

). This fixed it for me.

Comment: Seeing no explanation and no solution other than yours. I am awarding you bounty. You solution does work.

Comment: I've also come across this `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` but I haven't tracked down if it's any different than jangxx's example.

Comment: This fixed an issue for me as well...This is a beautiful fix! Thanks jangxx!

Comment: Was having the same issue on Chrome version 38.0.2125.104m. Can't believe this fixed it! It also seemed to make those transitions smoother!